# System.ObjectDisposedException - code works until I move it into another method

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

```
MyModel objRecord = new MyModel();
objRecord.ID = 42;
objRecord.Name = "Dave";
_context.CaseComplainants.Add(objRecord);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

List<MyOtherModel> lstRecord = new List<MyOtherModel>();
lstRecord = await _context.MyOthers
    .Include(p => p.Title)
    .Where(n => n.MyOtherID == objRecord.ID)
    .ToListAsync();
```

This code works fine if it's all in the same method.   When I move the second chunk into it's own method I get the error message

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object. A
>   common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved
>   from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same
>   context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you
>   are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a
>   using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let
>   the dependency injection container take care of disposing context
>   instances. ObjectDisposed_ObjectName_Name'

The `_context` is class wide and hovering over it shows what you'd expect.

The model looks like this.

```
public class MyOtherModel  {
    [ForeignKey("ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TitleID")]
    public int? TitleID { get; set; }
    public virtual LookUp Title { get; set; }
```

I've looked into the error message and all the problems that I can find are to do with the general set up of the EF infrastructure, one way or another.   I can't find one that talks about anything non-infrastructure related.

Any ideas why moving the code into another method breaks it?

**Edit**

The context is initialised in the boilerplate `ConfigureServices`, straight out of the example documentation

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddDbContext<MyContextModel>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyModel")));
```

This works

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync({
    MyModel objRecord = new MyModel();
    objRecord.ID = 42;
    objRecord.Name = "Dave";
    _context.CaseComplainants.Add(objRecord);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    List<MyOtherModel> lstRecord = new List<MyOtherModel>();
    lstRecord = await _context.MyOthers
        .Include(p => p.Title)
        .Where(n => n.MyOtherID == objRecord.ID)
        .ToListAsync();
```

This doesn't

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync({
    MyModel objRecord = new MyModel();
    objRecord.ID = 42;
    objRecord.Name = "Dave";
    _context.CaseComplainants.Add(objRecord);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    DoStuff(objRecord.ID);
}

private async void DoStuff(int TheID) {
    List<MyOtherModel> lstRecord = new List<MyOtherModel>();
    lstRecord = await _context.MyOthers
        .Include(p => p.Title)
        .Where(n => n.MyOtherID == TheID)
        .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: It would be useful to know how _context is created and stored. The exception says, it's been disposed.
Hoovering is not always helpful, in matter of disposing the Debugger behaves sometimes differently, than the actual Running Code. At least, you have to check the "IsDisposed" property, if it exists. A Reference to an object does not change at all by Disposing. Disposing just means "its no longer used". And it complains if you try to use it afterwards.

Comment: The project is utterly boilerplate, nothing fancy straight out of the sample code and documentation.   I've added the `ConfigureServices`if that helps.   I use `_context` in methods all over the project with no problems, but in this instance, putting the code in a separate method causes the error.

Comment: Are you sure the original code is running asynchronously, because if the calling method is not async aware, this will run in sync.  More info is needed to see the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I've added the header lines to the question to see if that helps

Comment: You are not awaiting `DoStuff`. It could be `OnPostAsync` returns before `DoStuff`can execute. When that happens the context is disposed, then `DoStuff` runs and you get the exception. Try `await DoStuff(objRecord.ID)`.

Comment: Brute Force: overwrite your `virtual void Dispose (bool disposing);` of your context just for Debugging and put a Breakpoint in (or do some other signalisation). See when, why by whom it is called, and if it is called at all.